# Azure classification using vba

Tags: excel, vba, azure, ms-word

I have a macro that creates and saves multiple word and excel documents. Recently, My organisation started using Microsoft Azure protection. It always asks the user to choose the classification label while saving the document. Is there a way we can pass the label from VBA? (i.e. controlling the classification via code)

I tried to search the existing questions and had no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution for Excel at least. I'am using similar method as [HaPi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10955799/hapi) for Outlook.

**At first**, set a label and use below code to check the object details of selected label (e.g. in `Locals` window):

```
Set current_label = ThisWorkbook.SensitivityLabel.GetLabel()
```

**Then** in new workbook create `label_info` object and fill it with details from `current_label` object:

```
Set label_info = ActiveWorkbook.SensitivityLabel.CreateLabelInfo

With label_info
      .ActionId = "" 'fill
      .AssignmentMethod = MsoAssignmentMethod.PRIVILEGED 'fill
      .ContentBits = 0 'fill
      .IsEnabled = True
      .Justification = "" 'fill
      .LabelId = "" 'fill
      .LabelName = "" 'fill
      .SetDate = Now()
      .SiteId = "" 'fill
End With
```

**At the end** use `SetLabel()` on current workbook:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SensitivityLabel.SetLabel label_info, CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
```

**Note:**

- Changes are not visible immediately, label is set in the background.
- There is no msgbox when saving the file with label selection.
- After reopening excel, the label is normally selected.
- I'm not sure what second `Context` argument does in `SetLabel()` function, so I've just created empty object there

**Test case:**

```
Sub set_label()
    ' Select label first
    Set current_label = ThisWorkbook.SensitivityLabel.GetLabel()
    
    msgbox "Check current_label details and fill below parameters"
    debug.assert False

    Workbooks.Add

    Set label_info = ActiveWorkbook.SensitivityLabel.CreateLabelInfo

    With label_info
          .ActionId = "" 'fill
          .AssignmentMethod = MsoAssignmentMethod.PRIVILEGED 'fill
          .ContentBits = 0 'fill
          .IsEnabled = True
          .Justification = "" 'fill
          .LabelId = "" 'fill
          .LabelName = "" 'fill
          .SetDate = Now()
          .SiteId = "" 'fill
    End With

    ActiveWorkbook.SensitivityLabel.SetLabel label_info, CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\wb with label.xlsx"
    Workbooks("wb with label.xlsx").Close True
End Sub
```

**Other resources:**

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/office/vba/api/office.labelinfo
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/office/vba/api/office.sensitivitylabel

Answer (score 5):

It seems that after more than a year there is still no solution. At least I did not find any native VBA integration for AIP.

However I found a solution for myself. Basically I create now a draft of a mail manually where I choose the classification manually. This draft remains in a special folder in outlook. Once I need to send a mail via VBA I copy the draft (classification included!), I change recipients, object, body and I am able to send it without user interaction from VBA since the classification is already done.

```
Private Sub Email()
    Dim oMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    'Set oMailItem = Outlook.Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    'Choose template according to subject
    'I have one template for each sensitivity classification
    Set oMailItem = getVbaTemplateMail("VBA Template - Sensitivity=General")
    With oMailItem
    .To = "mail@a.b"
    .subject = "Email Test using VBA"
    .Body = "Test"
    .Display
    .Send
    End With
    Set oMailItem = Nothing
End Sub

Private Function getVbaTemplateMail(subject As String) As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olFolder  As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
    'GetDefaultFolder(16) = Draft folder, "Drafts/VBA Templates" is my VBA Template folder
    Set olFolder = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(16).Folders("VBA Templates")
    For Each olItem In olFolder.Items
        Debug.Print olItem.subject ' Print to immediate window
        If olItem.subject = subject Then
            Set getVbaTemplateMail = olItem.Copy
            'If error "Active Inline Response" appears, the mail is open in Outlook, close it first!
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: I am looking for a solution for this but i haven't come across anything that suggests that there is a VBA solution for this yet but I like this as an alternative.. thinking outside the box :)

Answer (score 4):

**Azure Information Protection (AIP)**

The answer is **not currently**. See quote below.

I personally wouldn't have thought this likely given that it is a paid-for security feature.

**Interim solution:**

As an interim solution, depending on your needs, have you considered having your admin set a [default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/information-protection/rms-client/client-classify) classification?

> In addition to manually selecting labels, labels can also be applied
>   in the following ways:
>
> Your administrator configured a default label, which you can keep or
>   change........

1. Making sure the scoped policy includes your account.
2. If you have classify and protect, rather than just protect, more info is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/information-protection/rms-client/client-classify-protect).

**Feedback** from Microsoft indicates this ....

> might be solved with the new SDK that supports the programmatic
>   application of labels.  However, this SDK not yet available in public
>   preview.  You might be able to try it private preview if you ask about
>   it on the Yammer site: https://www.yammer.com/AskIPTeam

There...

> is User Voice entry for this SDK, ...[which may] be updated when it
>   becomes publically available ...if you vote for it, you also get
>   notified: https://msip.uservoice.com/forums/600097-azure-information-protection/suggestions/19602292-update-the-sdk-api-for-aip-to-include-classificati%C2%A0

The SDK documentation I saw, seemed to be in relation to C#, but that is just my observation. See developer link.

**Note:**

I did a quick search of their feedback site, [Ideas that relate to Azure Information Protection (AIP)](https://msip.uservoice.com/forums/600097-azure-information-protection?), for developments, using search terms `VBA` and `programming classification`, this yielded nothing.

This question has now been raised by a user here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/information-protection/get-started/infoprotect-tutorial-step4#comme

**Other resources:**

1. [Azure Information Protection Developer's Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/information-protection/develop/developers-guide)
2. [FAQs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/information-protection/get-started/faqs)
3. [Azure Information Protection Blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-Information-Protection/bg-p/AzureInformationProtectionBlog/label-name/Azure%20Information%20Protection)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have contacted my admin team requesting the same but the response was not positive. The line Document.Save2 makes the system freeze until I kill the word process in Task manager. I even tried to manipulate sendkeys (Ctrl + Shift + ~ is the shortcut for clicking the classification) but no luck yet.

Comment: Have you been making an attempt with code hence your comment?

Comment: Not exactly, I haven't written any lines on the AIP front. I was trying some other workarounds like send keys or clicking the ribbon button from vba. Couldn't get to any solutions yet.

Comment: I really don't think, by its very nature, that it would be amenable to intrusive efforts to change it's behaviour. I have sent a formal enquiry just to double check and will update my answer if I get a response.

Comment: Thanks much for your reply. Please update if you get a response.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my answer. It looks like you followed my link and have now raised. It has been noted. Let me know if this is a sufficient answer?

Comment: Yes, Sadly it appears to be I won't be able to control it from VBA.  Yes, I am the one who raised the same question in their site. I have now no option but to wait :(

Comment: Thanks I have closed it now

Answer (score 1):

I did not find a solution via API either. But I got it working smooth with SendKeys. Not the best solution, but it works. Maybe you have to adjust the characters. Be sure your Outlook email is in foreground. I execute the sendKeys right after ".display".

```
sendKeys "%" (ALT)
sendKeys "R"
sendKeys "Y1"
...
sendKeys "~" (ENTER)
```

Outlook Email Example:
[image: Outlook Email Example]

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to use this solution but when I press Alt it doesn't show me that many shortcuts, only the main ones (send, new, attach) how do you access the other ones? Thanks

Comment: I just figured it out. Thanks anyway!

Comment: This works well unless I execute another command immediately after. I have it trigger when an attachment is added. The settings are changed, but if I add a `.save` or even a `msgbox` after the `SendKeys`, the event fires before the keys are registered. (It closes the msgbox with the ~). I have the wait value set to true `SendKeys "%HY1{down}~",True` Any advice?

Comment: DoEvents after the SendKey command lets things catchup. Quote: _DoEvents passes control to the operating system. Control is returned after the operating system has finished processing the events in its queue and all keys in the SendKeys queue have been sent._

Comment: Using `Application.ItemSend` allows it to be applied to all outgoing messages. With the caveat of making sure all new emails are generated in a new window. The embedded drafting of emails makes for a different set of keystrokes.

Answer (score 1):

I got around the problem by adding custom properties to the document before saving the document.

```
docObject.CustomDocumentProperties.Add(Name:="MSIP_Label_<GUID>_Enabled",Type:=4,LinkToContent:=True,LinkToContent:=True,LinkToSource:=Body)
```

`<GUID>` will be the label's identifer. Can be inferred from a similarly labelled file by running command `Get-AIPFileStatus "<SimilarlyLabelledFilePath>"` in PowerShell.

`docObject` is the Word Application Object.

`LinkToContent` flags whether to link it to any specific content so it should be the `True` by default.

`LinkToSource` is the content you want to protect or place a label onto. I placed it on the `Body` in my case.

In case its an e-mail in outlook the complexity lies in placing the same thing in x-header, but as HaPi has way-around solution. Otherwise this solution by Marquise [https://stackoverflow.com/a/55761007/10213468] can be tried out.
Thanks to Eugene [https://stackoverflow.com/a/57413086/10213468] for the details which I worked around with.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the easiest way to do this is to attach a file that is already with the label that you want to send (e.g. General), and then the email will be already with that label.

If you are having the pop-up of the Outlook showing up and you don't like it, use the below code:

```
With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

the below code helps me select a classification on Outlook and sends the mail automatically,

```
Application.SendKeys "%s"
Application.SendKeys "{TAB}"
Application.SendKeys "{TAB}"
Application.SendKeys " "       
Application.SendKeys "%s"
```

Comment: Maybe try to explain why this code works, if possible.

Comment: hello Meow,  the codes above help you to automatically select a classification and then send the email. Instead of clicking on the azure outlook  pop up, the code does the "clicking" for you.

Answer (score 0):

As I still couldn't find any solutions online for this I stumbled over this site. The SendKeys option gave me a hard time because Outlook always seemed to ignore my entries.

Then I finally found the solution which works for me and I'd like to share for others who are struggling with this:

```vb
With oMsg
  .Display                          ' display message
                                    ' > enables you to navigate through menu with SendKeys
  With Application
    .SendKeys "%HY2~", True         ' send Alt, H, Y2, Enter
                                    ' > this enables first entry
                                    ' > add {TAB} or {DOWN} to navigate through entries
    .Wait Now() + TimeSerial(0,0,1) ' wait 1 second before resuming the code
                                    ' -> THIS is what stopped Outlook from not doing the changes
  End With

  ' ... here comes the rest of the mail code ...
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

For Outlook, I have gone through this issue with the following solution. I have created a new message, in "to" my email address... and send it, then I have to choose the email classification. When I receive it, I save it as a .msg file. And then I use it to create my emails, changing the values in "to", "cc", "subject", "htmlbody"... in order to send a set of emails, you need to close the .msg once the email has been set. Here is the code, it works perfect:

```
    Set MailItem = OutApp.Session.OpenSharedItem(msgRoute)
    'Change email, send and save with no changes
    With MailItem 
        .To = <New destination/s>
        .CC = <New cc value>
        .Subject = <New subject>
        .HTMLBody = <New email content>
        .Attachments.Add (atacchmentsroute)
        .Send
        .Save (olDiscard)
    End With
```

This code needs to be included completely into the loop for multiple email sending.

Answer (score 0):

Posting my solution in case it helps someone. I really wanted a .Net solution.
From my reading, there are two options to set the label automatically: either use VBA as described above, or in .Net configure an AIP/MIP solution which requires an authentication client. You can find out how to get started down this path [using Microsoft's tutorial here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/get-started-with-sensitivity-labels?source=recommendations&view=o365-worldwide). AIP will be deprecated soon.

The second option, using .Net automation, allows you to set the label on individual files using C#. You need the Microsoft Information Protection (MIP) SDK which is described [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/information-protection/develop/overview#microsoft-information-protection-sdk) To configure the MIP SDK requires change permission in AD, creating Security Principals, and registering the .Net app with correct permissions. Microsoft's [Quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/information-protection/develop/quick-app-initialization-csharp) page reads: "The MIP SDK implements authentication using class extensibility, which provides a mechanism to share authentication work with the client application. The client must acquire a suitable OAuth2 access token, and provide to the MIP SDK at runtime." This is a dead-end for me, because my company's IT has our AD and Azure cloud locked down tightly. It can be done but  will need several CREQ tickets and a few months for them to perform a security review and get it done.

So I solved this using a hybrid with both C# and VBA that is very similar to szewski's answer above. I created an MS Access db with one table to log the name and location of an incoming Excel file. I then added a macro with one RunCode line to execute my VBA. My C# code does this:

1. Drop the Excel file into a queue folder.
2. Add the file name to the Access db table.
3. Shell out to Access and run the macro: [Path]\MSACCESS.EXE [Another Path]\Sensitivity.accdb /x SensitivityLabel
4. The VBA code sets the label, moves the Excel to another folder, and updates the table to show work done.

Here is the VBA:

```
Public Function SetLabelInfo() As String

Dim db As Database, rst As Recordset, SQLstr As String, NewPath As String
Dim SensLabel As SensitivityLabel
Dim MyLabelInfo As Office.LabelInfo
Dim XL As Excel.Application
Set db = CurrentDb()
SQLstr = "SELECT * FROM FileLog WHERE Converted Is Null;"
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(SQLstr)
If rst.RecordCount = 0 Then
    Exit Function
End If
rst.MoveFirst
While Not rst.EOF
    Set XL = New Excel.Application
    XL.Workbooks.Open (rst![Filepath] & rst![FileName])

    'XL.Visible = True ' DEBUG

    Set SensLabel = XL.ActiveWorkbook.SensitivityLabel
    Set MyLabelInfo = SensLabel.CreateLabelInfo
    With MyLabelInfo
        .AssignmentMethod = MsoAssignmentMethod.PRIVILEGED
        .Justification = "Some justification"
        .LabelId = "cbec90da-8de3-41c2-83a2-9a36daf4eeff"
        .LabelName = "Confidential"
    End With
    SensLabel.SetLabel MyLabelInfo, MyLabelInfo
    NewPath = "Q:\SomeOtherFolder\"
    XL.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs NewPath & rst![FileName], XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    XL.ActiveWorkbook.Close
    XL.Quit
    Set XL = Nothing
    SQLstr = "UPDATE [FileLog] SET [Converted]=#" & Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") & "# " _
        & "WHERE [File_Key]=" & rst![File_Key] & ";"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL SQLstr
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    Kill rst![Filepath] & rst![FileName]
    rst.MoveNext
Wend
End Function
```

In my case there are only 3 labels to choose from, and I will always use the same one. I got the ID by checking it on another Excel file where it was already set. IMPORTANT: You must use a Label ID that matches one from your company's implementation.

MIP relies on the authentication on the app server where the automation runs, to meet the Sensitivity Policy requirements. So you do need to run the C# under a domain service account, which was no problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I used for word docs and Excel spreadsheets is documented here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74712674/add-sensitivity-label][1]

It shows how to get the required parameters for the label from and existing doc and then set them