# Azure Information Protection & Sensitivity Options in C#?

Tags: c#, excel, interop

We have reports that are automatically generated within Excel via Interop functionality in C#.

There were recent changes to the Microsoft Office suite amongst the teams that requires all documents to have a specifically classified "Sensitivity" option - this has some to do with GDPR laws in the being implemented EU.

Specifically, here's a quick FAQ, but I couldn't find anything with detail:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/information-protection/get-started/faqs

For example, opening a new spreadsheet gives "Sensitivity" options for Personal, Public, Confidential, Restricted (Confidential), etc.

Since these are required now for all documents, I suspect there will be a need to implement a programmatic way, in our existing C# code, to automatically assign a Sensitivity classification - likely 'Confidential.'

However, I am unable to find how this is done, or what the methods/options are to do this.

Is there any documentation on this, or details as to how to do this?

Sample shot of Excel sensitivity options:
[image: Excel Sensitivity Options]

Sample code, although I don't think it's pertinent to the question necessarily:

```
 Application xlObject = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
 xlObject.DisplayAlerts = false;

 Workbook xlMainWorkbook = xlObject.Workbooks.Add();
 xlMainWorkbook.SaveAs(("\\ReportFile", Env.XLFixedFormat);
```

Comment: To help track down Excel internal functions I start record a Macro, carry out the action and see what the resulting Macro does. Usually, from here, I am able to understand what needs to be done to translate in to C#

Comment: @JayV Given that the new Azure Sensitivity options aren't really well documented (I added a link), I still don't know that there's a way to do this specifically in C#.

Comment: @JayV I just checked - Macros are not recording Azure Information Protection settings at all.  They show any/all other steps, but AIP isn't being saved.

Comment: You may wish to refer to my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49003510/6241235

Comment: If you find anything useful and relevant feel free to add here or edit into my answer there. Also, if anything there is no longer accurate.

Comment: The solution given here is for VBA. There is no equivalent way to reach the Sensitivity Label in a C# .NET platform that I can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not supported, as the "Sensitivity Bar" is actually an Office Addin, which currently doesn't have any API.
You can try figuring it out using UI Automation 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32
To actually press the button.