# Add Azure default label to each email

Tags: excel, vba, azure, outlook

I am trying to default an Azure Protection label to an email. I am running an Excel macro to attach a file to an email.

This was working until Azure Protection came in. It now requires a label on every email, meaning the macro now needs manual intervention.

Is there a way in VBA to automatically add a default label to an Outlook email?
I was thinking of something like

`olMail.Properties("..`

or `olMail.ItemProperties.Add("...`

I can't find sample code or a solution.

Comment: did you try `send key` method?

Comment: No. You can't. I have answered this elsewhere. I will have a look and add the link here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49003510/6241235 The short answer is your IT dept maybe able to add a default label, not via VBA, but using the actual protection settings themselves. At least that was my understanding. I am happy to be corrected and update my prior answer.

Comment: @QHarr I believe you're correct as well.  There is lots of information about automatically applying the label with Outlook **[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/information-protection/deploy-use/configure-policy-protection)** and [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/information-protection/deploy-use/configure-policy-classification).  Other links [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=VBA+default+Azure+Protection+label+outlook).

Comment: Hi there, ok thanks.