# How I can set one of Azure information Protection Labels for email in Outlook in C#?

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, azure-information-protection

I have two Azure Information Protection Labels in Outlook from the server "Confidential" and "Confidential View only".
I need to check permission for recipients of email and if Azure labels not chosen, then set permission one of Azure Label.
How I can do it in C#?

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for this issue.
Every Azure Information Protection Label has a GUID, you can get from Azure server Administrator;

If need to set permission for MailItem just try this

```
MailItem item = Item as Outlook.MailItem;
string templateGUID = "{5F56C571-D3E0-4A06-8896-XXXXXXXXXXXX}";
item.PermissionTemplateGuid = templateGUID;
```

Comment: Did you try integrating with AIP/MIP SDK to set() the label? I believe that would a future proof way of applying a label programatically

Comment: I didn't try. Currently, we try to minimize any dependencies and queries to an external app.