# Close Microsoft Azure Information Protection bar

Tags: excel, vba, azure

Is there any way to connect Microsoft Azure Information Protection bar closing event with `Private Sub Workbook_Open()`? There is close button. Is there some way to close it automatically while opening the specific Workbook?

[image]

I am able to disable it from:

[image]

Here is the code to get Add-In ID:

```
Sub ListCOMAddins()
Dim lngRow As Long, objCOMAddin As COMAddIn
lngRow = 1
With ActiveSheet
      For Each objCOMAddin In Application.COMAddIns
         .Cells(lngRow, "A").Value = objCOMAddin.Description
         .Cells(lngRow, "B").Value = objCOMAddin.Connect
         .Cells(lngRow, "C").Value = objCOMAddin.progID
         lngRow = lngRow + 1
      Next objCOMAddin
End With
End Sub
```

Here is the result:

[image]

So this one `MSIP.ExcelAddin` should be disabled, but how? Maybe this can be done on Workbook open by VBA?

You can disable it by VBA if you have admin rights by:

```
Application.COMAddIns("MSIP.ExcelAddin").Connect = False
```

However I don't have admin rights to work computer and just disabled it from Add-ins manually and after computer restart it isn't there anymore. Would be good to do it by VBA anyway...

Comment: you cannot programmatically interact with AIP through vba.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49003510/6241235  See if there is an AIP setting itself. Refer to link for more info.

Comment: you mind be able to use windows api to target close button. Observation from @ErikA

Comment: @QHarr how this might be possible to target this specific button in this particular bar?

Comment: You cannot disable it for excel alone. At least not in the legacy (1.x) version. Starting from 2.x (Unified Labeling client), they are creating dedicated MS App based folders in appdata folder where now an individual policy file is present. May be MS is heading in that direction.