# Add sensitivity label

Tags: excel, vba, label

Search from google, but still have no idea how to select sensitivity label automatically
by VBA

[image: Add sensitivity label]

How to control it by VBA?

[image: select label]

Comment: Have you tried to recording a macro when you change the label?   I don't have access to this feature.

Comment: I have also not tested this. But [THIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.sensitivitylabel.setlabel?source=recommendations) looks promising...

Comment: or [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49003285/azure-classification-using-vba)?

Comment: see hint at [Excel confidential setting with VBA](https://community.blueprism.com/question/excel-confidential-settings-with-vbo) ?

Answer (score 4):

This solution worked for me.

First, I manually saved a document using the desired sensitivity label and then I used the code below to extract important parts of the sensitivity label, the site Id and the label Id.

```
Sub getlabel()

Dim myLabelInfo As Office.LabelInfo
Dim labelpart1 As String
Dim labelpart2 As String

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Set myLabelInfo = wb.SensitivityLabel.getlabel()

labelpart1 = myLabelInfo.LabelId
labelpart2 = myLabelInfo.SiteId

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

Range("A1").Value = labelpart1
Range("A2").Value = labelpart2

End Sub
```

Then the code below sets the labels for subsequent documents.

```
Sub setlabel()

Dim docSenseLabel As SensitivityLabel
Dim labelInfo As Office.labelInfo
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = Workbooks.Add 
Set docSenseLabel = wb.SensitivityLabel

Set labelInfo = docSenseLabel.CreateLabelInfo()
With labelInfo
    .AssignmentMethod = MsoAssignmentMethod.PRIVILEGED
    .LabelId = "the labelId you got"
    .LabelName = "Important or whatever label you saved earlier"
    .SiteId = "the site Id you got"
End With

docSenseLabel.setlabel labelInfo, labelInfo

wb.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\filename", FileFormat:=51
wb.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm finding such examples for Excel all over. Anyone got a pointer for doing the same with an Outlook Email? I can't find the level of the application that holds this label.

Comment: @EFH _MailItem_ objects contain the SensitivityLabel property. I'm not sure why you'd need to apply this to any other object.

Comment: There are two such labels. Both called sensitivity labels. I want the one set by Azure.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

Add the following piece to beginning of your code

```
'collect label information from the macro file
Dim LBInfo as office.labelinfo
set LBInfo = thisworkbook.sensitivitylabel.getlabel()
```

... Add this part before the code you save the new files

```
'set the same label to new files
NewFile.sensitivitylabel.setlabel LBInfo, LBInfo
Newfile.saveas "filename" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling to find the library that would accept use of "As SensitivityLabel", but found you don't need it:

```
Private Sub setSensitivitylabel()

    Dim docsenselabel = mxlWorkBook.SensitivityLabel
    Dim labelInfo = docsenselabel.CreateLabelInfo()

    With labelInfo      ' These values were obtained using getlabel(), commented out below
        .AssignmentMethod = 1   ' MsoAssignmentMethod.PRIVILEGED, The label was manually selected.
        .LabelId = ...
        .LabelName = "Internal"
        .SiteId = ...
    End With

    docsenselabel.setlabel(labelInfo, labelInfo)

End Sub

'' Ad-hoc method that can be used in a debugger to get the required Sensitivity label parameters
'' Leave this in but commented out
'Sub getlabel()
'    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application
'    Dim xlWb As Workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("...\InternalSensitivity.xlsx") ' Workbook that has been set to "Internal" using Excel UI
'    Dim myLabelInfo = xlWb.SensitivityLabel.getlabel()

'    Dim i = 1       ' Put a breakpoint here and look at the values of myLabelInfo
'End Sub
```