# Automatic excel sheet getting stuck on sensitivity status popup after macro being sent. - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Below is the VBA logic and I am trying to add logic in here so that after the Public Sub "btnSave_Click()" macro is clicked the popup for excel sensitivity selects "Internal Use" and keeps going. I know the Label ID as well if needed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNOWG.png)

tried referencing the below stack overflow but no success. Just got range errors.

[Add sensitivity label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74712674/add-sensitivity-)  label#:~:text=Sub%20getlabel%20%28%29%20Dim%20myLabelInfo%20As%20Office.LabelInfo%20Dim,%3D%20labelpart1%20     Range%20%28%22A2%22%29.Value%20%3D%20labelpart2%20End%20Sub

******update

Application.DisplayAlerts = False **ActiveSheet.SaveAs Filename:=strSaveLocation, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False (*this line right before this is where the macro generates a sensitivity label popup and now I need to insert vba logic so it selects "internal use*"** ActiveSheet.SaveAs Filename:=strBackupSaveLocation, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False ActiveWorkbook.Close

Comment: You should generally stop using `.Select` and `ActiveCell`. This will make it much easier to find / avoid the errors.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you mean by 'just got range errors' ... exactly what error (number and text) and on which line of code (ie so share, as text not as an image, the code that results in the error).

Comment: Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveSheet.SaveAs Filename:=strSaveLocation, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False (this line right before this is where the macro generates a sensitivity label popup and now I need to insert vba logic so it selects "internal use"
ActiveSheet.SaveAs Filename:=strBackupSaveLocation, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Close