# Set a sensitivity label for an excel workbook created from DOORS DXL

Tags: excel, vba, ole, ibm-doors

I'm trying to use DXL to set a sensitivity label for an excel file I'm generating from DOORS so I can save the excel file before going on and generating another one. I followed the link below and am able to automate this in VBA, but I am not able to do this in DXL. I run the oleGet function below and then try to set the Sensitivity Label for the Assignment Method Label, ID, Label Name, and Site ID parameters but it doesn't work and the script gets hung waiting on the user to manually select the label.

[Add sensitivity label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74712674/add-sensitivity-label)

oleGet( objActiveWB, "SensitivityLabel", objSensitLabel)

I've also tried to doing sense_label = oleCreateAutoObject("Office.LabelInfo") and then setting the labels attributes but sense_label always returns null. Anyone have any ideas?